# Given an array return any index on which its dominator occurs

Tags: c

Dominator is a value which occurs on more than half positions in an array. For instance in the array:
[3, 4, 3, 2, 3, -1, 3, 3]
the value 3 occurs in 5 out of 8 positions. 5/8 > 0.5,
so 3 is a dominator:
in this array the dominator occurs on indexes :
0, 2, 4, 6 , 7.
How to write a function that given an array returns any index on which its dominator occurs. If there is no dominator, the function should return -1.

Tried to solve it using C as:

```
int arrdominator(int *A,int N)
{
    int i,j,idx=0,val=0,cnt=1;

    //I thought I would sort the array and then cound the dominating value instances,
    qsort(A,N,sizeof(A[0]),sort_fn_ascend);

    for(i=0;i<(N-1);i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<N;j++)
        {
            if(A[i] == A[j])
            {
                cnt++;

                i++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i could not get to a solution of finding the dominator value in the array and then return its index.

Comment: You should use a debugger to find out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @DocBrown's pointers got my initial code refined to get it working alright:

```
int arrdominator(int *A,int N)
{
    int i,j,idx=0,cnt=1,valmaxseq,dominantval=0;
    int *newA = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        newA[i] = A[i];

    qsort(newA,N,sizeof(A[0]),sort_fn_ascend);


    for(j=0;j<(N-1);j++)
    {
        if(newA[j] == newA[j+1])
        {
            cnt++;              
        }
        else
        {               
            if(cnt > (N/2))
            {                   
                valmaxseq = newA[j];
                dominantval = 1;
            }

            cnt = 1;                
        }
    }

        //find index of dominant value if there is one
        if(dominantval == 1)
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            if(A[i] == valmaxseq)
                return i;
        }

        return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I am not going to solve this for you, you should *really* do this on you own, but here are some hints:

- first, since your spec says you must either return an *array* of indexes (or -1), I suggest you change the signature of your function accordingly
- second, you should split up the task into parts. First part (after sorting): determine the length of the longest sequence of equal numbers (and the repeated number of this sequence). Then, test if the sequence if longer than N/2. If so, find out the indexes where the number occurs and return this result. Since you are going to solve this by sorting, make sure you keep a copy of the original array since you will need it to determine the original indexes.
- if `cnt` is for counting the sequence length, you must reset it to zero every time you start counting a new sequence. And you will need a second variable `maxSequenceLength` to keep the length of the longest sequence found so far, as well as a third one `valOfMaxSequence`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. OP says "it should return any index of the dominant value". So not an array of indexes as you think.

Comment: I am not a native speaker, but I guess one can interpret "any" as "each" here. It seems not to be clear from the words you were using. Perhaps you should check what was asked originally in your programming test.

Answer (score 2):

I will show you how to do it in Python which reads almost like english.
You will still have to rewrite it to C, so it is not technically cheating ;)

```
array_of_numbers = [3, 4, 3, 2, 3, -1, 3, 3]
array_length = len(array_of_numbers)
highest_count_value = 0
highest_count = 0
for each_number in array_of_numbers:
    each_count = array_of_numbers.count(each_number)
    if each_count > highest_count:
        highest_count_value = each_number
        highest_count = each_count

highest_count_value_indices = []
for each_index, each_number in enumerate(array_of_numbers):
    if each_number == highest_count_value:
        highest_count_value_indices.append(each_index)

highest_count_value_is_dominator = True if highest_count > (array_length / 2.0) else False

print("Array: "+`array_of_numbers`)
print("Possible dominator: "+`highest_count_value`)
print("Possible dominator count: "+`highest_count`)
print("Is it dominator? : "+`highest_count_value_is_dominator`)
print("Indices of dominator: "+`highest_count_value_indices`)
```

There are better and faster ways to achieve this, but I tried to stick to simple methods, so it reads almost as meta programming.

Also the part about returning -1 if there is no dominator is simple enough at this point, right?

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of this? I've just thought of using the count algorithm in C++. So my answer would be:

```
int denominator(const vector<int> &A)
{
    int vecSize = A.size();
    //test for empty vec
    if (vecSize ==0)
        return -1;

    //count number of elements in vec then check if count > size/2
    for (int i = 0; i < vecSize; i++)
    {
        int c = count(A.begin(), A.end(), A[i]);
        if (c > vecSize/2)
            return i;
    }

    return -1; //denominator not found
}
```